# How to set a new logging level on kube-proxy, in a running cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

Is there a way to change the logging level on a running cluster, specifically for a single system component such as kube-proxy?

I see some discussion related to this:
https://github.com/kubernetes/test-infra/pull/4311
and it seems like some sort of a mechanism was put in place, but it is not clear to me how to use this mechanism.

This question came about because we are troubleshooting connections to a NodePort service (which should go through kube-proxy), and at the default level of --v=2 kube-proxy doesn't seem to log any of the connections that it proxies, so seeking to increase it.

Answer (score 2):

> it seems like some sort of a mechanism was put in place, but it is not clear to me how to use this mechanism

I didn't see anything in that PR that would lead me to believe there is a dynamic (that is: without terminating `kube-proxy`) mechanism for altering log levels. There is no dynamic logging adjustment mechanism that I'm aware of in any of the kubernetes components.

However, `kube-proxy` (traditionally) runs in a docker container just like any other Pod, and thus is subject to being restarted on termination. So just update its `--v` in the manifest, kill the container (the one without `Pod` in its name), and `kubelet` will start `kube-proxy` back up, now with the new `--v` level.

> (which should go through kube-proxy)

Just for clarity, `kube-proxy` only manages the `iptables` rules in its default configuration, and so no traffic flows through it that I'm aware of. That's actually why it's safe to just restart `kube-proxy` at will.

You can examine the rules it puts into place with the regular `iptables -t nat -L` command, and `kube-proxy` is even helpful enough to add comments to the rules, showing which kubernetes service they represent.